# Get a checkbox to delete itself

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel form which dynamically creates entries based on user input.
The input creates a checkbox, to mark if the task is complete, etc.

Is it possible to use the value of the check box to remove the check box and the entry?

I.e. If the user ticks the checkbox, then the entry and the checkbox are deleted.

```
private sub Checkbox1_click()
   If Checkbox1.Value = true 
       checkbox1.delete
   end if
end sub
```

This throws the following error:

> an invalid procedure call or argument error.

Is there a way to get a checkbox to delete itself?

Comment: Which language are you using, really?

Comment: VBA, as the tags say.

Comment: Then it is not VB6

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, try to hide instead of deleting like this:

```
Private Sub Checkbox1_click()
    CheckBox1.Visible = Not CheckBox1.value
End Sub
```

Anyway, make sure that you save somewhere the fact, that the `CheckBox1` is not visible, because it will show the next time the form is initiated. You may save it in a variable or in a cell.